# XCTestCase async

Tags: ios, xctest, xctestcase

I have XCTestCase in scenario

In XCTestCase body, there are set of test cases.
The issue that I only want all the test cases begin after the very first test case finish successful (in my special purpose the first test case response a **token** for other test case using).

I don't want to add parameter **token** to other test cases.

So basically, the tests file look like this

```
class MyTestCase: XCTestCase {

    var token: String!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        self.continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    func testGetToken() {
        asyncGetToken { token in
            self.token = token
            // From now, the test1 and test2 should be started.
        }
    }
    func test1() {
        //using token to make request etc
    }

    func test2() {
        //using token to make request etc
    }
}
```

Anyone suggest for simple solution?

Comment: It's best for tests to be completely independent from one another. That means that the behavior of one test shouldn't depend on the result of another test and that the tests should be able to run in any order.

Comment: If all tests depend on the same initial state and the only thing that `testGetToken` does is to set up that state then you could do that in the test case's `setUp` (waiting for the async result before finishing set up).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should move the token retrieval into the `setUp` method, which will allow the token to be retrieved before every test, and also keeps your tests independent from one another.

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    self.continueAfterFailure = false

    let tokenExpectation = expectation(description: "get token")
    asyncGetToken { token in
        self.token = token
        tokenExpectation.fulfill()
    }
    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [tokenExpectation], timeout: 5)
    XCTAssertEqual(result, .completed)
}
```

Comment: Note that `asyncGetToken` is asynchronous and that `setUp` will most likely finish before the token has been retrieved and assigned.

Comment: In that case, XCTWaiter can be used to delay the completion of setUp

Comment: Edited to include a waiter

Comment: expectation is needed for async job that is observed on main thread, or we will get a deadlock. Actually, I already did this way, but I also wanna it as independent test instead of embed in **setUp** function. Anyway, thanks your help @Oletha